# How do you set the value from children list to parent list

Tags: java

Inheritance in Java. Is it possible to do like this:

```
List<ParentEntity> loc = Locations,
```

where `Locations` is `List<ChildEntity>`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicit

Comment: Why would anyone want to do something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Rohit Jain said, his answer is limited.

You can have a workaround like this :

```
List<ParentEntity> loc = new ArrayList<ParentEntity>()
loc.addAll(locations);
```

This time, the limitation is that you lose the initial type of List implementation. And, more importantly, any modification to loc won't be seen on locations.

Answer (score 5):

**No you can't** do that. Polymorphism is not allowed in generics.

However you can do: -

```
List<? extends ParentEntity> loc = new ArrayList<ChildEntity>();
```

Oh yes, you won't be able to add any new item to your list after that assignment, except `null`. That's a restriction you have to bear with.

So, you can first create your `ArrayList<ChildEntity>`, fill it, and then assign it to `the LHS`.

Comment: And he wont be able to add anything else than `null` to his list

Comment: Sorry, I had to reassign the answered mark to Jerome. His solution really helped me. I've just test it. Anyways thank you very much!

Comment: @Sergey.. Ah! common. It's absolutely all right. You never have to feel sorry for changing your accepted answer. Accept the most suited answer, wihout 2nd thought. :)

Comment: Thank you! :) In any case this answer helped me as well

Comment: @Downvoter..  Any particular reason for downvote that you think I deserve to know?